# Will my cat grow out of suckling?

Tags: cats

My cat is 8 months old and sucks on me until he is ready to go to sleep. He gets nothing from it. He seems to like my wrists the best. I have tried stopping him but he is so persistent. My question do you think he will out grow this.

Comment: when was he taken from the mother cat at what age.

Comment: Welcome to pets Rhonda! Please view the questions I have added to your question, they will have the answers you are looking for :)